# Introductory Vue production build with npm getting stuck

Tags: docker, vue.js, nginx, npm

I'm attempting to learn Vue, Nginx, and Docker. I'm trying to follow the tutorial provided at the following link: [Vue CLI Tutorial](https://mherman.org/blog/dockerizing-a-vue-app/). The development environment works well and I was able to develop a full single page application in that method with hot reloading. However, I'm now trying to create a production version but the Dockerfile listed get stuck on the "RUN npm run build" command as it just never moves on to the next command.

Below is the Dockerfile

```
# build environment
FROM node:lts-alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package.json /app/package.json
RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm install @vue/cli@3.7.0 -g
COPY . /app
RUN npm run build

# production environment
FROM nginx:stable-alpine
COPY --from=build /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Result from attempting to build

```
 => [build 1/7] FROM docker.io/library/node:lts-alpine@sha256:1ccc70acda680aa4ba47f53e7c40b2d4d6892de74817128e  0.1s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/node:lts-alpine@sha256:1ccc70acda680aa4ba47f53e7c40b2d4d6892de74817128e0662d3  0.1s
 => CACHED [build 2/7] WORKDIR /app                                                                             0.0s
 => CACHED [build 3/7] COPY package.json /app/package.json                                                      0.0s
 => CACHED [build 4/7] RUN npm install --silent                                                                 0.0s
 => CACHED [build 5/7] RUN npm install @vue/cli@3.7.0 -g                                                        0.0s
 => CACHED [build 6/7] COPY . /app                                                                              0.0s
 => [build 7/7] RUN npm run build                                                                             247.8s
 => => #   dist/css/main.140db4ed.css           9.70 KiB           2.40 KiB
 => => #   Images and other types of assets omitted.
 => => #   Build at: 2023-05-30T02:33:49.953Z - Hash: 26e8978a41c3bbd5 - Time: 10710ms
 => => #  DONE  Build complete. The dist directory is ready to be deployed.
 => => #  INFO  Check out deployment instructions at https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html
```

No matter how long your wait, it never moves on from this message.

I've seen other problems reported in a similar manner, but no real solutions provided.

Below is the default package.json created by the vue-cli in case that is relevant.

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "vue": "^3.2.13"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.16",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead",
    "not ie 11"
  ]
}
```

Comment: This seems to be the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76295345/17438890 No clear answer thought…

Comment: Agreed, came across that one but didn't see a real answer. Going to try a fresh Vue project via the CLI and see if that helps with the production build.

Comment: Trying to use Vue v3 with Vue CLI is only going to cause problems and you won't find good instructions. Suggest you switch to the official [Vite build](https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html) instead